# Is there a standard treesitter construct for parsing an arbitrary-length list?

Tags: treesitter

One very common parsing scenario in programming languages is an arbitrary-length nonempty list of elements with a separator, for example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f(a, b, c)
```

I've been parsing this in treesitter as follows:

```
list: $ => seq(
  repeat(seq($.element, ',')),
  $.element
)
```

This works, but it's common enough that I wonder whether treesitter has a built-in construct for it. Does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In several grammars, (e.g. [Rust](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-rust/blob/40620bf4097cbc9cea79504d7e877865df43a19e/grammar.js#L1443-L1449), [Go](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-go/blob/c03e250fe4b4021b0a0c81cf63b143371987ad40/grammar.js#L860-L866)), we define helper functions for this.

```
function commaSep1(rule) {
  return seq(rule, repeat(seq(',', rule)))
}

function commaSep(rule) {
  return optional(commaSep1(rule))
}
```

We could include these functions as part of the Tree-sitter DSL, but since it's so easy to
define your own helper functions like this, I think it's best to keep the DSL small.